# Kafka Streams error "TaskAssignmentException: unable to decode subscription data: version=4"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

During deployment with only changed Kafka-Streams version from `1.1.1` to `2.x.x` (without changing `application.id`), we got exceptions on app node with older Kafka-Streams version and, as a result, Kafka streams changed state to error and closed, meanwhile app node with new Kafka-Streams version consumes messages fine.

If we upgrade from `1.1.1` to `2.0.0`, got error `unable to decode subscription data: version=3`; if from `1.1.1` to `2.3.0`: `unable to decode subscription data: version=4`.
 It might be really painful during canary deployment, e.g. we have 3 app nodes with previous Kafka-Streams version, and when we add one more node with a new version, all existing 3 nodes will be in error state. Error stack trace:

```
TaskAssignmentException: unable to decode subscription data: version=4
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.assignment.SubscriptionInfo.decode(SubscriptionInfo.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamPartitionAssignor.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:520)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:472)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:455)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:822)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:802)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:563)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1149)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:831)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:788)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:749)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:719)
```

Issue is reproducible on both Kafka broker versions `1.1.0` and `2.1.1`,  even with the simple Kafka-Streams DSL example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("default.key.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
props.put("default.value.serde", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde");
props.put("application.id", "xxx");

StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
streamsBuilder.<String, String>stream("source")
        .mapValues(value -> value + value)
        .to("destination");
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), props);
```

Is it a bug of kafka-streams? Does exist any workaround to prevent such failure?

Comment: this may be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6054 seems to be fixed in newer versions

Comment: There might be a bug in the fix provided via KAFKA-6054: -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8649 -- if you can reproduce the issue reliably, please comment on the Jira and share logs if you can so we can fix it.

Comment: Not sure who quickly you roll/bounce each instances, but I assume the error should not occur if you give enough time between rolling different instances. -- Btw: the issue should not be related to brokers, but it seems to be a Kafka Streams issue.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax issue is reproducible in 100% cases and not depend on the number of app instances with previous Kafka Streams version (an error occurred for both cases with either one or three app nodes having Kafka Streams 1.1.1), during deploying the first app node with new Kafka Streams version. Added comment to Jira `KAFKA-6054`.

Comment: as I see, the problem is in implementation of Kafka Streams `1.1.1` `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.assignment.SubscriptionInfo` . With new version `2.3.0`, `decode` implementation already take into consideration that we might receive newer `latestSupportedVersion`, but still seems new version will not decode appropriately.

Comment: The fix for KAFKA-8649 will be including in upcoming 2.4.0, 2.3.1, and 2.2.2 releases.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for the update